# Passing down location props to a components that is not routed

Tags: reactjs

Hey guys i want to pass a location props to a NavBar,
however i cant do it since it not a routed component,
its always there,and location comes back undefined

Any Suggestions?

The Code:

```
  <Router>
        <NavBar  location={this.props.location}></NavBar>
    <Switch>
      <div className="wrapper">
        <Route exact  path="/" component={Home} />
        <Route path="/about" component={About} />
        <footer>Footer</footer>
      </div>
    </Switch>
  </Router>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the component you are rendering it doesn't have a this.props.location, then it won't have the location to pass down to NavBar.

Though, I'd recommend using either [`withRouter`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/withRouter) or [`useLocation`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Hooks/uselocation) in your NavBar component if it needs access to the location without being a Route itself. As a note, `useLocation` is only usable in hook components